# ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends - on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, pip, cryptography

I am getting the import error,

ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends
There was a problem importing our SSH library (see traceback above).
Please make sure all dependencies are installed and importable.

I followed these suggestions mentioned online:

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip install cryptography --force-reinstall

**but on reinstalling cryptography module I am getting unicodedecode error:**

---

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:46909:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘X509_get_signature_nid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   return X509_get_signature_nid(x0);

   ^

build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: In function ‘_cffi_d_i2d_re_X509_tbs’:

build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:50059:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘i2d_re_X509_tbs’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   return i2d_re_X509_tbs(x0, x1);

   ^

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AM7c2T-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

**Please suggest how to fix this.**

Comment: Python 2 has reached its end of life last year. It sounds like a bad idea to rely on discontinued software for security-related stuff like cryptography...

Comment: What can be done if security is not a concern..since i am dealing with dummy data.